# Javascript Regex (x,y) Match multiple

Tags: javascript, regex

I am newbie to Javascript.

What regex will be used to match the following expression type. Please note that there could be spaces between digits.

```
(3,2), ( 2,3),(5, 4)
```

I am trying as (\d+,\d) but this is not working for multiple pairs of (x,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the RE below: `\s*` means: "any whitespace". The parentheses have a special meaning, and have to be escaped.

The first RE just matches all pairs of numbers, while the second RE also group the numbers, so that they can be referred when using the `RegExp.exec` function.

```
/\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)/g

/\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/g
```

Example, get all (x,y) pairs within a string, and store the pair in an array:

```
var source = "(1,2), (3,4) (5,6) (7,8)"; //Comma between pairs is optional
var RE = /\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/g, pair;
var pairList = [];
while((pair = RE.exec(source)) !== null){
    pairList.push([pair[1], pair[2]]);
}
//pairList is an array which consists all x,y pairs
```

Comment: I am trying your answer but it is not working for atleast this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: See the example at the bottom of my answer. @PujanSrivastava, your website doesn't accept the slashes and the flags of a RE.

Answer (score 0):

this should match (x,y),(v,w) like patterns. 0 to n (x,y), expresions plus 1 (x,y) expresion (including whitespaces)

```
/(\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\),\s*)*\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
patt = RegExp('\(\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*\),{0,1}', 'g')
patt.test("(3,2), ( 2,3),(5, 4)") => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `/(\(\d+\s*,\s*\d+\)*)/g.exec('(2,3), (3,4)')` or using the string at the start  `'(2,3), (3,4)'.match(/(\(\d+\s*,\s*\d+\)*)/g)`